# How to create/make movable SVG based shaped and connectors/line like in a flowchart in angular without using any third party licensed software?

Tags: html, angular, svg

```
<g id='Start'  transform='translate(0,60)'>
<circle id='Rect_Start' r='40'cx='125' cy='10'  style='fill: white;stroke: gray;stroke-width: 1.5;' > 
</circle>
<text id='SvgjsText19'  x='105' y='15' style=' font-size: large;' >Start</text></g>

<g id='SvgjsG117' transform='translate(125 50)'>
<polygon id='SvgjsPolygon1188' points='-10,20 10,20 0,40' fill-opacity='1' fill='grey'></polygon>
<line id='SvgjsLine189' x1='0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='40' stroke='grey' stroke-width='1.5'></line></g>

<g id='SvgjsG118'  transform='translate(0 100)'>
<rect id='r1' class= 'RectClass'  width='280px' height='50' rx='5' ry='5' style='fill: white; > 
</rect>
<text id='SvgjsText119'  x='10' y='20' style='font-size: large;'>hello </text> </g>
```

> in above code,  a circle svg is created and a line is connected to another svg rect like a flowchart.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

  elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
}

#mydivheader {
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" >
<svg id="mydivheader" height="200" width="200">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" />
</svg> 
</div>
```